# Make div stay on click Jquery asp.net

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a div appear on click and then stay on the screen, but cannot make the div stay once clicked?

Here is the Jquery used:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){             

        $(function () {
            $("#main").hide();
            $("#Button1").on("click", function () {
                $("#main").toggle(500);
            });

        });

    });
```

and the html for the main :

```
#main{
        position:absolute;
        left:180px;
        width:75%;
        height:700px;
        top:300px;
        background-color:snow;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your `button` doesn't submit the page. If it's a plain html button, add attribute `type="button"` in the tag.
 Another option is to prevent the submit in the click event handler:

```
$("#Button1").on("click", function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#main").show(500);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in this line:

`$("#main").toggle(500);`

The "toggle" function in jQuery will make an element's display state toggle between hidden and shown. To simply have the element be shown when you click, use the "show" function.

```
$(function () {
    $("#main").hide();
    $("#Button1").on("click", function () {
        $("#main").show(500);
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi @Dylan Stark, I have just tried your suggestion, which makes perfect sense to me, but for some reason the div still does not stay on the screen.  I'm not sure whether this is a complication with asp.net, as I have used similar code in NetBeans and the div stayed on the screen after clicking the button?

Comment: @kehoewex86 is the div briefly showing up on click and then disappearing? The only real way for anyone to help is if you include more info, or a codepen or jsfiddle.